# Sorting 2 arrays in Swift based on alphabetical order of one of the arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I am creating a new array, `alph_hostArtists: [String]`, which sorts `hostArtists` in alphabetical order. I then need to arrange a new array `alph_hostSongs` such that the index of each "song" matches each "artist" as is defined in `hostArtists` and `hostSongs`. I would use a dictionary, but the problem is there can be duplicate songs and artists in each array that do not share the same artist/song.

```
var hostArtists: [String] = ["z", "a", "d", "d", "1"]
var hostSongs: [String] = ["bb", "yy", "cc", "56", "bb"]
var alph_hostSongs: [String] = hostSongs.sorted
{
    $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) ==  NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}
```

Comment: The 3rd line: `var alph_hostSongs: [String] = hostSongs.sorted`, is it supposed to be `var alph_hostArtists: [String] = hostArtists.sorted`?

Comment: Yes it is. I accidentally swapped them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question directly in swift 1.0, you can zip, sort, and map.

```
var alph_hostSongs: [String] = Array(Zip2(hostArtists, hostSongs)).sorted {
    $0.0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.0) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}.map {
    return $0.1
}
```

---

The real answers is to create a struct to hold both artist and song. That way they are always linked together.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for newIndex in 0...alph_hostArtists - 1 {
    for origIndex in 0...hostArtists - 1 {
        if hostArtists[origIndex] == alph_hostArtists[newIndex] {
            alph_hostSongs.append(hostSongs[origIndex])
        }
    }
}
```

What it does is finds at which index the new array's element is from the old set, then appends that to the new set. Be warned that if there are multiple songs from the same artist(which there will be), the songs will be arranged not by song alphabetical order, but by the order they are entered in